# How to 'properly' turn the name 'Hardy' into an eponym? E.g. "Hardy-ian", "Hard-ian", "Hard-enian"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-usage

I was conversing about G. H. Hardy's book, '*A Mathematician Apology*', and I had had wished to describe a part of his ideology as an eponym, but it didn't sit well with me. I do not know of a 'proper' way to describe that, I thought of '*Hardyian*', but that sounded bizarre to me.

Am I correct in my original choice (i.e. '*Hardyian*'), or is there no 'correct' or better way?

##### Examples

**A**:

> My choice to become a mathematician is not *Hardyian*.

**B**:

> The *Hardian* apology, as I see it, is not truly a mathematician's apology.

**C**:

> Is '*Hardyian*' or '*Hardian*' the 'proper' eponym? If neither, what is? Is there such a thing as a 'more' eponymous thing?

---

P.S.: do not give alternative ways to amend the phraseology as a work-around, if you do not have an answer, then simply don't attempt one... thanks.

Comment: His name was _Hardy_, with a Y. What's wrong with spelling it _Hardyan_? It'd be pronounced the same in any case, and this way it'd represent his name.

Comment: @JohnLawler, I thought of that solution, but I didn't know if it constituted a 'proper' eponym since it is a play on phonetics. I thought of other examples, like 'America' v. 'American', or 'Austria' v. 'Austrian', 'Egypt' v. 'Egyptian'; interestingly, others broke that precedent, 'Taiwan' v. 'Taiwanese' instead of 'Tawian-ian', or ''Epicurus' v. 'Epicurean' instead of 'Epicur-ian'/'Epicur-en' (i.c. 'Epicuru-n' seems close). 

Summarily, the precedents make me weary of that change... Then again, this is English, I suppose a lot of things are not that 'bizarre', or 'wrong', or what have you.

Comment: Part of it depends on your audience, too; a layperson would easily assume that Georgian relates to George and Victorian to Victoria, but it's a bit more of a jump to realise Caroline refers to Charles and Jacobean refers to James.

Comment: Thank you, @Showsni. I think I'll pick '*Hardyan*'.

Comment: _Hardyesque_ is a [popular option](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Hardian%2CHardyian%2CHardyan%2CHardyesque&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHardian%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHardyian%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHardyan%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHardyesque%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CHardian%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHardyian%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHardyan%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHardyesque%3B%2Cc0), but perhaps it has a slightly different meaning: in the manner of Hardy, rather than directly pertaining to Hardy.

Comment: The eponym of Hardy is "Hardy" - the adjective from Hardy is Hardian.

Comment: @TonyK, mouthful though! Thank, nonetheless.

Comment: @Greybeard, please read carefully. I said, "I wish to describe part of his ideology (...)", not him, the person. Obviously, '_Hardy_' is derived from '_Hardy_'. An Eponymous thing is an adjective per se. E.g. America is American. Egypt is Egyptian. Austria is Austrian. Epicurus is Epicurean.

We don't want to run into a self-referential paradox here, as the original post wished, we could focus on his ideology, not him, for all intents & purposes.

Comment: @ASN How do you understand the title: "How to 'properly' turn the name 'Hardy' into an eponym?"?

Comment: @Greybeard, the same way as I've described in my previous comments, evidenced by the examples (both in the title, and in the body of the question/post), and if not clear, the question itself surely did away with any 'confusion'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a famous writer named Thomas Hardy. The eponym for him is either *Hardyan* or *Hardian*. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Hardian%2CHardyian%2CHardyan&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10). I'd suggest using which of these you prefer. *Hardyan* has a less usual ending, but it also makes clear that you're referring to *Hardy* and not somebody named *Hard* or *Harde*.

A couple of sentences using this:

> Like Orestes, who cannot escape the chants of the Furies, the Hardyan narrator is haunted, but unlike Orestes, he gives voice and visage to the haunting.
>
> But the heroes and heroines of the great Hardian tragedies are all drawn from the lowest rank of life.

Comment: Thank you, Peter.

Do you've a comment on why one or the other became naturally a precedent? Or is the scope a little too wide to answer that specifically?

Comment: Yes. On seeing 'Hardyan', without prior context, I'm pretty sure most people will think the reference is to Thomas Hardy. But perhaps an audience of mathematicians wouldn't.

Comment: It's only unclear that 'Hardian' refers to 'Hardy' because 'Hardy' is already improper. 'Hard' describes G.H., so the proper nomenclature is G.H., Hard. "Hardian" is then perfectly natural. The mathematician will doubtless appreciate querent's correct usage. /s

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The OP has shown that there is indeed enough context to make it clear which Hardy they refer to,

Comment: @Rosie F Yes ... but I'm thinking about other situations. The title question is more general. Here, Peter starts by mentioning the famous writer, and 'Hardyan' will default to referencing him or his works in most contexts.

Comment: [_Hardyesque_](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Hardian%2CHardyian%2CHardyan%2CHardyesque&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHardian%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHardyian%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHardyan%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHardyesque%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CHardian%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHardyian%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHardyan%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHardyesque%3B%2Cc0) beats all of your options -- in fact it beats the _sum_ of your three options, and has done since about 1946. But the meaning is perhaps slightly different.

Answer (score 8):

The traditional way of eponymisation in English is to first latinise the word and then form an eponym appending *-ian* or similar.
For example, cf.
*[Oxonian](https://www.lexico.com/definition/oxonian),
[Cantabrigian](https://www.lexico.com/definition/cantabrigian),
[Norwegian](https://www.lexico.com/definition/norwegian),
[Shavian](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/459750/42471),
[Harrovian](https://www.lexico.com/definition/harrovian),
[Venetian](https://www.lexico.com/definition/venetian).*
It’s up to you whether traditional is actually good here.

If you go this way, *Hardius* is a better Latinisation than *Hardyus,* since the Latin language does not natively feature the letter *y,* and here it is not essential to the word but an ending (as opposed to e.g., *Babylon → Babylonian*). Thus you arrive at *Hardian.*

Comment: That is very interesting, Wrzlprmft! Though, some words might be difficult to attempt, or expert, at latinising. (It is interesting nonetheless!)
I did pick '*Hardyan*' from the other answers since the context seems to be sufficient insofar as the discussion itself was concerned. I iterate: thanks nonetheless!

Comment: Is Shavian supposed to refer to G.B. Shaw? If I saw that outside a discussion like this I'm pretty sure I wouldn't make that leap.

Comment: @Barmar: *Is Shavian supposed to refer to G.B. Shaw?* – … or anybody else with that surname; yes. Also see the link.

Answer (score 2):

I've come across an example in a work on [Fundamentals of Mathematical Evolutionary Genetics; Yuri M Svirezhev and Vladimir P Passekov](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Fundamentals_of_Mathematical_Evolutionar/Fl7uCAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22hardian%22&pg=PA138&printsec=frontcover) (p 138):

> ... the Hardy-Weinberg Principle holds ...
>
> If (3.9b) holds, the population need not be Hardian ...

(Please read for specific statements.)

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Weinberg_principle) confirms that this does refer to G H Hardy. I think the lengthy article avoids the adjective 'Hardian', using the compound attributive form (*Hardy–Weinberg* proportions) instead.

Comment: Good find, Edwin! In my initial search, I looked at some of his publications with _Little Wood_, that amounted to: nothing. I looked at the end notes of the book itself, and he mentioned a few colleagues of his from the literature department, looked them up, and found nothing too.

I think this is equivalent to Peter's answer, if not better, as it is specific. Thank you, Edwin.